# .htaccess rewrite url get?

Tags: .htaccess, url, get

```
/watch.php?id=1

/watch/1/seo-url-827372
```

and

```
/category.php?id=1

/category/1/seo-url-734774
```

I have a server that supports .htaccees how can I implement these rules with rewrite .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Your usecase is a bit more than just `.htaccess` - yes, it's possible to do it only with `.htaccess` but it's stretching it - you would have to write redirects from the top to the bottom URLs(meaning write the hard coded URLs in `.htaccess` - possible, but not recomended).

More common use case would be to have the `seo-url-827372` also in the original URL (something like `/watch.php?id=1&url=seo-url-827372`) and then use `.htaccess` to rewrite it.

[Have a look here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) for a nice, detailed explanation (with examples).

Comment: My apache version 2.2 this document don't recommend me